# Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.masterpage_mpname_master' to type 'ITest'

Tags: asp.net

I am developing a web application. I have created an interface ITest

```
public interface ITest
{
    void Add();
}
```

& a usercontrol which implements ITest

```
 public partial class WebUserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl, ITest
    {
        public void Add()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

On my webpage i have placed usercontrol. but, when i typecast the usercontrol to type IType it throws an Exception(System.InvalidCastException)

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
  //          WebUserControl11.Add();
            foreach (var uCnt in this.Page.FindControlsOfType<UserControl>())
            {
                if (uCnt.Visible)
                {
                    ((ITest)uCnt).Add(); //Error : Casting Exception
                }
                else
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**I can call Add method directly** but, I want to call it using ITest Interface

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the `FindControlsOfType` method implemented but suppose that you need to retrieve controls those implement ITest interface instead of all UserControl instances.